# Laravel: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, laravel

I get data from looping in `station_id` to get data from the schedule.

```
$stations_id = Station::pluck('id'); // Output [1,2,3,4]
$schedules = [];
foreach ($stations_id as $station_id) {
     echo $schedules = Schedule::select('id')
                        ->where('station_id', $station_id)
                        ->latest()
                        ->first();                
     }
```

The echo of `$schedules` output is:

> {"id":16}{"id":17}{"id":15}

But the issue is here, I have tried to loop through `$schedules` to get a data from another table called `Queue`,   I mean I want to get latest queues of every schedule we are looping in it.

So I did it like this:

```
$queues = [];
foreach ($schedules as $schedule) {       
    echo $queues = Queue::withTrashed()
                 ->latest()
                 ->where('schedule_id', $schedule);               
}
```

but it showed this error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I didn't know where I missed it.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `$schedules` isn't an array when you finish your first loop. You'll want `$schedules` to be an **array** after your first loop:

```
$stations_id = Station::pluck('id'); // Output [1,2,3,4]
$schedules = [];
foreach ($stations_id as $station_id) {
     $schedules[] = Schedule::select('id')
                    ->where('station_id', $station_id)
                    ->latest()
                    ->first();                
}

// second loop here

$queues = [];
foreach ($schedules as $schedule) {       
    $queues[] = Queue::withTrashed()
             ->latest()
             ->where('schedule_id', $schedule->getKey())->first();               
}

// do something with queues
```

Comment: is there a way to make it an array, cause iam so confused

Comment: I made it an array, see my answer.

Comment: thanks @adam, but if echo queue it doesnt returning any value, you it should right!

Comment: i think it's getting worse now there's error "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string" is that suppose to appear!

Comment: Maybe ask a new question for that problem.

Comment: @Lafoune, my previous comment had an error. I've updated the answer to reflect the correct solution.